# "Cannot run test (h_c: is_deeply($n, $s)) with active children at /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/Test/More.pm line 1020"

Tags: perl

Trying to convert some code from `use Test::more` to `use Test::Builder` I got this problem when trying to use `is_deeply` (perl 5.18.2):

> Cannot run test (h_c: is_deeply($n, $s)) with active children at /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/Test/More.pm line 1020

The manual for `Test::Builder` states this example for `explain`:

> is_deeply($have, $want) || diag explain $have;

However `Test::Builder` does not have the `is_deeply` method, but `Test::More` has it (I used `use Test::More 'import' => [qw(is_deeply)];` to import only that).
Unfortunately when trying to use it from a sub-test (`$tb->child()`), the program dies with the message cited above.

Is there a way to use `is_deeply` in a sub-test?

Message from within the Perl debugger:

```text
Cannot run test (h_c: is_deeply($n, $s)) with active children at /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/Test/More.pm line 1020.
 at /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/Test/Builder.pm line 1969.
        Test::Builder::croak('Test::Builder=HASH(0x1b6e3c0)', 'Cannot run test (h_c: is_deeply($n, $s)) with active children') called at /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/Test/Builder.pm line 769
        Test::Builder::ok('Test::Builder=HASH(0x1b6e3c0)', 1, 'h_c: is_deeply($n, $s)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/Test/More.pm line 1020
        Test::More::is_deeply('HOTP::Core=ARRAY(0x31131c8)', 'HOTP::Core=ARRAY(0x310ab10)', 'h_c: is_deeply($n, $s)') called at otptest.pl line 96
```

## More Details

As I failed to extract a minimum example, I dug into the code I have.
Line 1020 of `Test::More` is `$ok = $tb->ok( 1, $name );` (so the actual test succeeded).
The interesting fact is `$tb` that is not the `Test::Builder` child instance used in the caller, but a local instance created in `is_deeply` as `my $tb = Test::More->builder`.
That instance has a child that is the first-level child of my `Test::Builder` (that's not finished yet, of course), so the test `$self->{Child_Name}` in line 766 of `Test::Builder::ok` fails.

I'm tempted to make a copy of `is_deeply` passing the correct `Test::Builder` instance instead of creating a local one.

Anyway, here's the best approximation of the failure scenario I could make:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::Builder;
use Test::More 'import' => [qw(is_deeply)];

sub t2($$$)
{
    my ($TB, $a, $b) = @_;

    $TB->plan('tests' => 4);
    $TB->ok(1, 't2.1');
    $TB->ok(1, 't2.2');
    is_deeply($a, $b, 't2.is_deeply');
    $TB->ok(1, 't2.4');
    $TB->finalize();
}

sub t1($$$)
{
    my ($TB, $a, $b) = @_;

    $TB->plan('tests' => 2);
    t2($TB->child('t2'), $a, $b);
    $TB->ok(1, 't1.2');
    $TB->finalize();
}

sub main()
{
    my ($a, $b) = ([1], [1]);
    my $TB = Test::Builder->create();
    my $subtest = sub($) { $TB->diag($_[0]); return $TB->child($_[0]); };

    $TB->plan('tests' => 1);
    t1($subtest->('t1.1'), $a, $b);
    #t1($subtest->('t1.2'), $a, $b);
    $TB->done_testing();
}

main();
```

And this is the output I got:

```text
  DB<0> c
1..1
# t1.1
    1..2
        1..4
        ok 1 - t2.1
        ok 2 - t2.2
ok 1 - t2.is_deeply
        ok 3 - t2.4
        # Looks like you planned 4 tests but ran 3.
    not ok 1 - t2
    #   Failed test 't2'
    #   at foo.pl line 72.
    ok 2 - t1.2
    # Looks like you failed 1 test of 2.
not ok 1 - t1.1
#   Failed test 't1.1'
#   at foo.pl line 84.
# Tests were run but no plan was declared and done_testing() was not seen.
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
```

### Insights

When debugging the code, I realized that my actual program used `Test::Builder->new` instead of `Test::Builder->create` (as in the minimal example). That made the difference (also see  my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78159022/6607497):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::Builder;
use Test::More 'import' => [qw(is_deeply)];

sub t2($$$)
{
    my ($TB, $a, $b) = @_;

    $TB->plan('tests' => 4);
    $TB->ok(1, 't2.1');
    $TB->ok(1, 't2.2');
    #local $Test::Builder::Test = $TB;      # ugly and dangerous!
    is_deeply($a, $b, 't2.is_deeply');
    $TB->ok(1, 't2.4');
    $TB->finalize();
}

sub t1($$$)
{
    my ($TB, $a, $b) = @_;

    $TB->plan('tests' => 2);
    t2($TB->child('t2'), $a, $b);
    $TB->ok(1, 't1.2');
    $TB->finalize();
}

sub main()
{
    my ($a, $b) = ([1], [1]);
    my $TB = Test::Builder->new();
    my $subtest = sub($) { $TB->diag($_[0]); return $TB->child($_[0]); };

    $TB->plan('tests' => 1);
    t1($subtest->('t1.1'), $a, $b);
    #t1($subtest->('t1.2'), $a, $b);
    $TB->done_testing();
}

main();
```

```text
Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.39_10
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(foo.pl:42):      main();
  DB<0> c
1..1
# t1.1
    1..2
        1..4
        ok 1 - t2.1
        ok 2 - t2.2
Cannot run test (t2.is_deeply) with active children at /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/Test/More.pm line 1020.
 at /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/Test/Builder.pm line 1969.
        Test::Builder::croak('Test::Builder=HASH(0x2003c58)', 'Cannot run test (t2.is_deeply) with active children') called at /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/Test/Builder.pm line 769
        Test::Builder::ok('Test::Builder=HASH(0x2003c58)', 1, 't2.is_deeply') called at /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/Test/More.pm line 1020
        Test::More::is_deeply('ARRAY(0x1d12770)', 'ARRAY(0x2476030)', 't2.is_deeply') called at foo.pl line 15
        main::t2('Test::Builder=HASH(0x2508560)', 'ARRAY(0x1d12770)', 'ARRAY(0x2476030)') called at foo.pl line 25
        main::t1('Test::Builder=HASH(0x25116e0)', 'ARRAY(0x1d12770)', 'ARRAY(0x2476030)') called at foo.pl line 37
        main::main() called at foo.pl line 42
        # Child (t2) exited without calling finalize()
    not ok 1 - t2
    #   Failed test 't2'
    #   at /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/Test/Builder.pm line 1969.
    # Child (t1.1) exited without calling finalize()
not ok 1 - t1.1
#   Failed test 't1.1'
#   at /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/Test/Builder.pm line 1969.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
# Looks like your test exited with 29 just after 1.
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
```

When un-commenting the  `local` line, the output is instead:

```text
main::(foo.pl:42):      main();
  DB<0> c
1..1
# t1.1
    1..2
        1..4
        ok 1 - t2.1
        ok 2 - t2.2
        ok 3 - t2.is_deeply
        ok 4 - t2.4
    ok 1 - t2
    ok 2 - t1.2
ok 1 - t1.1
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
```

Comment: I think Test::More uses Test::Builder under the hood. So it will manage its own Test::Builder object internally and this will give conflict with the Test::Builder object used in your script. You might need to create your own version of is_deeply() instead of using Test::More

Comment: Note: Sorry, I was not paying attention when asking the question: I had searched the net first, and I arrived at "Super User". Not paying attention I pressed "Ask a question", so it ended up in Super User. Sorry! Now the question is where it should have been right from the beginning.

Comment: Not sure why you want to get rid of Test::More ? If it's really what you want to do, maybe have a look at [Test::Deep](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Deep).

Comment: @smonff You should have tried: The POD says: "*If you want to control what functions `Test::More` will export, you
have to use the 'import' option.  For example, to import everything
but 'fail', you'd do:

  `use Test::More tests => 23, import => ['!fail'];`*"

Comment: Maybe provide an extract from your code so that we can reproduce the exact case.

Comment: When trying to create a simple test example, the test example did not trigger a problem. I'll have to investigate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the effect is caused by several bugs in `Test::Builder`:

1. When using `Test::Builder->new()`, a "copy" of the returned objects is saved as `$Test::Builder::Test`, but that "copy" is actually a copied reference, so that setting the number of tests in the object(s) returned by `new` also changes the number of tests in `$Test::Builder::Test`.
2. `is_deeply` from `Test::More` should be a method of `Test::Builder` actually, but it uses its own lexical instance of `Test::More->builder`.  That, in turn. returns the value of `$Test::Builder::Test`. Naturally that won't work for nested tests (i.e.: children of `Test::Builder`).

My solution was to add `local $Test::Builder::Test = $TB;` just before calling `is_deeply`.

In addition I could have used `Test::Builder->create()`instead of `Test::Builder->new()`, but that still would not fix the output of `is_deeply`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have so many odd situations in your code, such as the prototypes and the internals shenanigans, that you are making it very difficult for you to succeed. As you note in your own answer, `Test::More` has some issues, but they aren't bugs. It's working as designed. The design, however, is decades old and from another time, which is why the maintainer is trying to get Test2 into core.

Here's a simple Test module that re-uses Test::More's `is_deeply`. You mentioned stuff about references, but `Test::Builder->new` uses a singleton. You are always going to get the same reference. `Test::More` accesses this through `Test::Builder::Module::builder()`. This is noted in the docs for `Test::Builder::new()`. You shouldn't be messing with anything else, and you don't need to pass it around.

```
package MyTest;

use Test::Builder;
use Test::More import => [qw(is_deeply)];

my $t = Test::Builder->new;

use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT = qw(always_ok never_ok deeply_ok);

sub always_ok {
    $t->ok(1, "this always passes");
}

sub never_ok {
    $t->ok(0, "this always fails");
}

sub deeply_ok {
    is_deeply $_[0], $_[1], 'I can use Test::More::is_deeply';
}

1;
```

And here's a program that uses it. This program merely uses a couple of modules and does not know how they work. This program doesn't try to coordinate anything. It merely uses the exported functions:

```
use lib qw(...);

use Test::More;
use MyTest;

always_ok();
never_ok();

deeply_ok( [ qw(1 2 3) ], [ qw(1 2 3) ] );

deeply_ok( [ qw(1 2 3) ], [ qw(a b c) ] );

subtest 'foo' => sub {
    deeply_ok( [ qw(1 2 3) ], [ qw(1 2 3) ] );
    deeply_ok( [ qw(1 2 3) ], [ qw(a b c) ] );
    };

done_testing();
```

The output brings you back to the problem that you were having before with the file and line that Test::Builder reports. In this case, since the failure is actually inside something that `deeply_ok` calls, one level up from that is in the `MyTest` module (so you get something like `at /Users/brian/Documents/MyTest.pm line 21.`).

```
ok 1 - this always passes
not ok 2 - this always fails
#   Failed test 'this always fails'
#   at test.pl line 7.
ok 3 - I can use Test::More::is_deeply
not ok 4 - I can use Test::More::is_deeply
#   Failed test 'I can use Test::More::is_deeply'
#   at /Users/brian/Documents/MyTest.pm line 21.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->[0] = '1'
#     $expected->[0] = 'a'
# Subtest: foo
    ok 1 - I can use Test::More::is_deeply
    not ok 2 - I can use Test::More::is_deeply
    #   Failed test 'I can use Test::More::is_deeply'
    #   at /Users/brian/Documents/MyTest.pm line 21.
    #     Structures begin differing at:
    #          $got->[0] = '1'
    #     $expected->[0] = 'a'
    1..2
    # Looks like you failed 1 test of 2.
not ok 5 - foo
#   Failed test 'foo'
#   at test.pl line 16.
1..5
# Looks like you failed 3 tests of 5.
```

However, you can tell a function how far up the stack an error should be reported by setting the value of `$Test::Builder::Level`. Using the example straight out of the docs, this changes `deeply_ok` to:

```
sub deeply_ok {
    local $Test::Builder::Level = $Test::Builder::Level + 1;
    is_deeply $_[0], $_[1], 'I can use Test::More::is_deeply';
}
```

Now the output shows the errors from the perspective of one more level up, which is the test file itself.

```
ok 1 - this always passes
not ok 2 - this always fails
#   Failed test 'this always fails'
#   at test.pl line 7.
ok 3 - I can use Test::More::is_deeply
not ok 4 - I can use Test::More::is_deeply
#   Failed test 'I can use Test::More::is_deeply'
#   at test.pl line 11.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->[0] = '1'
#     $expected->[0] = 'a'
# Subtest: foo
    ok 1 - I can use Test::More::is_deeply
    not ok 2 - I can use Test::More::is_deeply
    #   Failed test 'I can use Test::More::is_deeply'
    #   at test.pl line 15.
    #     Structures begin differing at:
    #          $got->[0] = '1'
    #     $expected->[0] = 'a'
    1..2
    # Looks like you failed 1 test of 2.
not ok 5 - foo
#   Failed test 'foo'
#   at test.pl line 16.
1..5
# Looks like you failed 3 tests of 5.
```

Notice how many things you are trying to force into your code just aren't necessary. Excise all that stuff, especially when you are making minimal, reproducible examples. Also, I've written plenty of test modules, as have many other people. Check out the source, as I had recommended previously, to see how easy this can be. Everything I needed to do this is in the top level docs for `Test::Builder`.

Comment: I don't "pass it around", but pass a child of the builder. Also I fail to see the difference after messing with the level. Maybe it's because you use `subtest`, while I was using `child`.

Comment: Look at your code. Your are passing some variable `$TB` as an argument. Don't do that. subtest has nothing to do with it. You're simply doing it wrong.

Comment: Well, for a sub-test I pass the result of `TB->child()` to the sub-test, because the sub-test as such, could have sub-sub-tests, recursively. IMHO that is a cleaner approach than messing with the global `$Test::Builder::Level` locally. If you are talking about something different, please be more specific.

Comment: As you see in my code, you don't need to do that. The docs say to use `$Test::Builder::Level`. It's what the module expects you to do. You are doing it wrong and that's causing your problems.

Answer (score -1):

The following seems to manage to import `is_deeply` successfully in a `Test::Builder` suite. Tested on Perl 5.26 though.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::Builder;
use Test::More import => [qw(is_deeply)];

my $t = Test::Builder->new;

my $data = [{ a => 'b'}];

$t->subtest(
    'Import is_deeply only',
    \&test_me,
    $data,
);

$t->done_testing();

sub test_me {
        my $args = shift;
        my $expected = { a => 'b'};
        is_deeply $args->[0], $expected, 'I can use Test::More::is_deeply';
}

1;
```

Comment: I was doing my sub-tests via the `child` method to create a "sub `Test::Builder`.